# When I use "=" to copy an object, why are the source and destination values different?

Tags: c++

I am copying an object, but the source and destination values are different. I am not sure what happened. `temp_mode`is not the same as `default_mode` after the copy,

[image]

```
bool display_device_info::change_resolution(int width,int height)
{
    DEVMODE temp_mode;
    temp_mode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    temp_mode.dmDriverExtra = 0;

    temp_mode=default_mode;

    temp_mode.dmPelsWidth = width;
    temp_mode.dmPelsHeight = height;
    bool res=ChangeDisplaySettings(&temp_mode, 0);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is correct behavior. You have the original object and the copy, which are two different objects. The object addresses are different (as well as the addresses of `dmDeviceName`, which is what is visible in the screenshot). If you want two variables pointing to the same address, you should use pointers instead of copying.

Comment: thanks for your help ,i had just think they are shallow copy ,so address should be same ,so why it's a deep copy ?when i copy a char arry or string ,it's just a shadow copy?

Answer (score 1):

The first element of the attachment (`dmDeviceName`) you gave us is the adress of the variable, so this is normal they are different !

Comment: thanks for your help ,i had just think they are shallow copy ,so address should be same ,so why it's a deep copy ?when i copy a char arry or string ,it's just a shadow copy?

Answer (score 1):

Are you wondering why `dmDeviceName` seems to be on different addresses?

That is because the `dmDeviceName` member is an *array* and not a pointer. The contents of the array is copied, but the array itself is stored on a different location. The location itself is irrelevant, only the contents of the array matter.

Copying a structure by assignment is equivalent to calling [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) for the structure.

So

```
temp_mode=default_mode;
```

is equivalent to

```
memcpy(&temp_mode, &default_mode, sizeof temp_mode);
```

Comment: thanks for your help ,i had just think they are shallow copy ,so address should be same ,so why it's a deep copy ?when i copy a char arry or string ,it's just a shadow copy?

Comment: @huaichengpan It *is* a shallow copy, it only copies the members of the structure themselves. But since one member is an array the whole array is copied. If it were a pointer only the pointer would be copied.